# R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc

Tags: raspbian, realtek

I got Raspberry Pi 2 as my birthday gift (woohoo), I then download:

RASPBIAN (Debian Wheezy) (2015-02-16)

After booting into Linux, I'm not seeing `wlan0` when I issue `ifconfig`, I also seeing following message after issuing `dmesg`:

> R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc

I'm trying to use [USB Wireless Network Adapter - USB to Wireless N Adapter | 802.11N | StarTech.com](http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Wireless/USB-150Mbps-Mini-Wireless-N-Network-Adapter-802-11n-g-1T1R~USB150WN1X1)

Please advise

Comment: *"Any ideas how to deal with it?"*  Deal with what?  A message in dmesg?  Sure, just ignore it.  **Is there an actual problem you are having,** or are you just getting obsessive-compulsive about what's in the logs?

Comment: @goldilocks you're right, sorry about that... I forgot to include main thing)

Comment: If you edit it in I'm happy to reopen this, but poke @goldilocks so I don't miss it.

Comment: How about if you use `ifconfig -a`?  Without the `-a`, interfaces that are down won't be shown.

Comment: @goldilocks same output as without `-a`. I also checked adapter itself on Windows 8.1 and I was able to connect without any issues, so at least I know adapter is working.

Comment: Have a look at `lsusb` and see if it is listed there.  If so, edit that line into the question.  If not, list the make and model.  Have you used this adapter with a pi before?

Comment: @goldilocks unfortunately `lsusb` isn't listing my adapter, per your suggestion I updated my question with adapter information. I never used this adapter with pi before.

Comment: That it doesn't show the adapter at all is a bad sign -- even if there is no possible driver, it should do that.  There are some adapters listed  [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) that use that chipset (RTL8188EUS); I actually have one of them (a TL-WN725) that works but it gets very very warm on the pi.   Unfortunately manufacturers usually don't provide linux drivers and they have to be reverse engineered by volunteers, so there is not 100%  coverage.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to your problem in Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange ([Wifi Dongle not appearing in lsusb](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27462/wifi-dongle-not-appearing-in-lsusb)), you need to install youre wifi dongle's firmware. 
Quoting the accepted answer:

> From the dmesg output, you see that the driver r8188eu recognizes the
>   WiFi dongle, but cannot load firmware for it, since the firmware file
>   cannot be found.
>
> The Raspberry Pi forum has two threads about getting these WiFi
>   devices to work under Raspbian.
>
> Normally USB devices can be seen in the lsusb output even if a
>   suitable driver is not available. I believe the dongle did not show
>   up, because it is disconnected when the firmware is not found, as the
>   last two dmesg lines show.
>
> I found that the regular Debian package firmware-realtek contains the
>   required file. This would be a clean and convenient way to get it, but
>   on my Raspbian I don't have this file, even though the package is
>   installed.

and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62371) I found the one for my raspbian (#781)
and the firmware can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/blob/master/rtl8188eufw.bin) (just clic on "raw")

Comment: Where do I get firmware file from?

Comment: you didn't read the links provided in the original post... https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

Comment: but in fact you don't need that firmware file for ALL versions of raspbian. the older just need the correct driver version

Comment: #781 does not need the firmware. but #793 does